# Cannot list changed files using github actions

Tags: yaml, github-actions

I am trying to list all the changed files on file push. However my `List all changed files` command does not return anything even though I change the file and commit

> ```
> name: test on:   push:
>     branches: [ main ]
>
> jobs:   build:
>     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
> steps:
>   - uses: actions/checkout@v2
>     with:
>       fetch-depth: 0  # OR "2" -> To retrieve the preceding commit.
>
>   - name: Get changed files using defaults
>     id: changed-files
>     uses: actions/checkout@v2
>
>   - name: List all added files
>     run: |
>       for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.added_files }}; do
>         echo "$file was added"
>       done
>
>   - name: List all changed files
>     run: |
>       for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.modified_files }}; do
>         echo "$file was modified"
>       done
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the one available in marketplace https://github.com/jitterbit/get-changed-files#get-all-changed-files

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a bug with your code

Replace

```
  - name: Get changed files using defaults
    id: changed-files
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

With

```
  - name: Get changed files using defaults
    id: changed-files
    uses: tj-actions/chnaged-files@42
```